# Flutter 2: Change a data sent to a child from the parent

Tags: flutter

For all the future answers, the code has to be split in two files.

I have my PARENT file containing :

```
class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  const Parent({
      Key key
    }) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _ParentState createState() => _ParentState();
  }

  class _ParentState extends State<Parent> {
    String text = 'This have to be changed from the parent';

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // when press it change the text contained in the child
          },
          child: Child(
            test: text,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

I have my CHILD file :

```
class Child extends StatefulWidget {
  final String test;

  const Child({
    @required this.test,
    Key key
  }) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _ChildState createState() => _ChildState();
  }
  
  class _ChildState extends State<Child>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin<Child> {
    String test;
  
    @override
    void initState() {
      test = widget.test;
      super.initState();
    }
  
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        child: Text(test),
      );
    }
  }
```

As you can see by reading the code, I would like from the parent to change my child value, but I don't know how.

This is an example of my problem with an easier understanding code (because the one which is stuck is quite big), so the `with TickerProviderStateMixin<Child>` is normal because in my other code I apply animations. I have just reproduced my need.

Could you provide help please?

Comment: have you tried `setState` and change the `text` value on it in your parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Parent Widget, you can change the state using `SetState`:

```dart
class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  const Parent({
      Key key
    }) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _ParentState createState() => _ParentState();
  }

  class _ParentState extends State<Parent> {
    String text = 'This have to be changed from the parent';

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState((){
                text = 'my new text value';
            });
          },
          child: Child(
            test: text,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

In your child widget, don't save your text in a State variable. The `initState` is only called once. if a dependent value changes, The whole state probably wouldn't be recreated from new. instead a way better approach is to use a getter or use the widget value directly in the child widget:

```dart
class Child extends StatefulWidget {
  final String test;

  const Child({
    @required this.test,
    Key key
  }) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _ChildState createState() => _ChildState();
  }
  
  class _ChildState extends State<Child>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin<Child> {
    String get test => widget.test;
  
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        child: Text(test),
      );
    }
  }
```

Also, it seems you are not using flutter 2.0. It's been out for quite a while now. if you just started, consider migrating now.

Comment: Ok well I see, this is so easy ! I don't know how I didn't thought about it x) Well thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

In your onPressed on Parent change the text and then setState

```
  onPressed: () {
      text = 'New Text';
      setState(() { });
    },
```

Comment: It missing the part String get test => widget.test; and your response should be good !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setState((){})` methode with StatefulWidget
When `setState((){})` methode called, your `build()` methode re run automaticly and flutter ui canvas rendered again so your text on your screen change.

Your new Parent Widget can be like below

```
class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
 const Parent({
  Key key
}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ParentState createState() => _ParentState();
}

class _ParentState extends State<Parent> {
String text = 'This have to be changed from the parent';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        text = 'Your new text here';
        setState((){});

        /* Or another way
           setState((){text='your new text here';});
        */
      },
      child: Child(
        test: text,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

}

For more info you can visit [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)

Comment: String get test => widget.test;